# maintaining many pandas dataframe at once

Tags: python, pandas

I just want to filter my dataframes by value of row and when I put them in list just they value in list updated nut out of list let me clarify it by two ways that I did:

**First way:**

```py
ls_lst = [df_ls_c,df_ls_bc,df_ls_ab,df_ls_on]
def rowFilter(df,row,value):
    df = df[df[row] == value]
    return df

for df in ls_lst:
    rowFilter(df,"column1","value5")
```

**Second way:**

```py
for i in range(4):
    ls_lst[i] = ls_lst[i][ls_lst[i]["column1"] == "value5"]
```

How can I do it to update data frames out of ls_lst, too?

Comment: What do you mean by "out of `ls_lst`"? All dataframes in your global environment?

Comment: @Cainã Max Couto-Silva Yes exactly when I use methods like df.dropna() with using inplace=True it changed all dataframes out of list but code above don't do, what's the solution? I tried to use global keyword but wasn't work !